# Recover deleted offline files

Tags: networking, windows-10, offline-files

I tuned on the offline availability feature for one of my network folder. After turning it off,  I accidentally deleted the copy of the offline folder. Is there a way to recover that folder?

Comment: Have you looked in the Recycle Bin?

Comment: @DavidPostill it's not there